# How am I supposed to handle disruption in a Perilous Journey?

Tags: dungeon-world, moves

**Undertake a Perilous Journey** is perhaps my least favourite basic move.

The intention seems to be to abstract the specifics of a perilous journey, which is useful.  My issue comes with the fact that a *perilous* journey seems to always require lowering the level of abstraction to deal with *peril*, and the move sort of breaks down leaving me unsure of what to do.

My agenda and the very text of the move itself encourage me to add some adventure into the mix:  Goblin's attack, you find a cool cave etc. So I end up with stoppages to deal with all the cool stuff. This is fine but when the encounter is handled the party usually wants to resume their journey.  I am never sure if I should just complete the journey based on the stale roll from earlier or if they trigger the move again.  I've played with both, but neither really seems to "work" for me.

This is particularly an issue because my party loves to start journeys with little or, more often, no food.  So running out of food and foraging *every day* is not uncommon for our journeys.  This creates lots of stoppages and exacerbates the issues with the move.  The stoppages are *fun*, collecting food and exploring places isn't a chore, especially in the perilous wilds.  Its the weirdness with the journey move that gets in our way.   Either you are rolling for each leg of the journey, or you end up with a really outdated roll hanging over the party for a long time.

How should this move be done?  How is it supposed to interact with stoppages?

Comment: When you say "the perilous wilds", are you being poetic, or referring to the third-party supplement *The Perilous Wilds* and the problems you're having using its variant on the **Undertake a Perilous Journey** move?

Comment: @Glazius That was accidental.  I have the perilous wilds and I should probably read their variant of the move but I am talking about the basic move in vanilla DW.

Answer (score 8):

### Let it ride.

It's interesting that you use "the perilous wilds" - that's actually the name of a Dungeon World supplement from Lampblack and Brimstone, the same publishers of the *Freebooters on the Frontier* setting you've talked about using before. It provides an interesting contrast to Dungeon World's philosophy in that the *Perilous Wilds* mode for traversing or exploring a perilous wilderness is to roll for one day's travel at a time, going as far as you can before you Make Camp. (Also, you may find their move for foraging for rations adds to your repertoire, even if you don't adapt the system.)

In contrast, Dungeon World treats a perilous journey much differently:

> A perilous journey is the whole way between two locations. You don't roll for one day's journey and then make camp only to roll for the next day's journey, too. Make one roll for the entire trip.
>
> This move only applies when you know where you're going. Setting off to explore is not a perilous journey.
>
> -- "Undertake a Perilous Journey", [Moves Discussion](https://github.com/Sagelt/Dungeon-World/blob/master/text/Moves_Discussion.xml) on the SRD

The philosophy was called "Let It Ride" in much earlier games, but in Dungeon World it's never really explicitly called out, just an assumed part of the link between moves and fictional actions. If you're trying to run from one castle tower to another without the dragon assaulting the castle noticing you, you don't mark out distance and pace and make multiple *defy danger* "stealth rolls" to move between intermediate covers on the way. Crossing from one tower to another is a single interesting thing and it's resolved in a single roll. ...well, maybe. Maybe when you're thinking about it you actually want to break the whole thing up because of how far apart the towers are, or maybe the *defy danger* partially succeeds and they get an ugly choice between pushing themselves hard enough to hurt or stopping in cover to catch their breath. But if you think of it as a single fictional event, you resolve it as a single move.

*Undertake a Perilous Journey* works the same way. It's the same wilderness as it was before, and you already know how well the PCs can navigate it, so even if you have multiple dramatic side adventures, you don't reroll.

#### ...unless the table's changed.

Or perhaps as a result of one of your dramatic side adventures, the wilderness *has* changed, or the PCs have. You went deep into a cave and it collapsed behind you, and you chose to keep going; now you've come out somewhere different and you're not entirely sure where. Maybe you've made allies with a local wilderness expert who's offered you some tips on making shortcuts or looking for wild forage to stretch out your supplies. Or in less happy news, maybe the PC you were counting on to scout your way to the destination has passed the Black Gates of Death and someone else needs to take their place.

In that case, you've created a notably different circumstance with your adventure, and you're justified in restarting the perilous journey from where you are now. (As an additional note I know it's generally discouraged to sit in front of moves and give them +X or -X, but as an improvisational GM tool I find it useful to steal some tech from later PbtA games and give one-off "advantage" and "disadvantage" for temporary situations, replacing the basic 2d6 roll with 3d6 drop highest for a Trailblazer roll from an unknown position, or 3d6 drop lowest for Quartermaster after a local expert tells you how to recognize the good swamproot.)

So when it feels like the old roll has staled out, ask yourself why. If circumstances are different from what they were when you started out, then restart the journey from where you are now. If it's just something your playgroup has trouble wrapping their heads around, maybe you'd be better off adopting the *Perilous Wilds* system instead.